# Buck Converter - Closed Loop - Effect of decreasing inductance and increasing capacitance

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, inductor, buck

Output voltage as a function of output current is plotted from oscilloscope data for a closed loop buck converter.

Switching frequency is kept the same in both the cases.

**CASE 1** **: Inductance = 2.2mH/Capacitance = 1uF [Closed Loop]** 
[image]

**CASE 2**: **Inductance in decreased to 1mH and the capacitance is increased to 22uF [Closed Loop]**
[image]

I have to compare these results. I know that increasing the inductance effectively moves the buck converter into DCM.

However, in closed loop control conditions, the waveforms look almost identical. is there any difference? am I missing something?

Comment: Which waveforms look the same?  Did you check step response? LC products are different.

Comment: Please provide more information:  controller used, switching frequency, and any other piece of information you may feel important.

Comment: Are you sure the inductance is in mH and not uH? Unless your switching frequency is very low, these inductances are huge.

Comment: actually  frequency & LC values have nothing to do with load regulation error  (steady state)  but greatly affect step response.

Comment: The main concern when you reduce the inductance is that the ripple current will increase. You have to make sure that DC current + 1/2 of ripple current is below the current saturation level of your inductor.

Comment: What is the regulation mode, voltage- or current-mode control? In VM, the dc open-loop output resistance of the buck converter is \$r_L\$ (the inductance series resistance) in parallel with the load resistance. \$r_L\$ is smaller for a 1-mH inductor than for a 2.2-mH (more turns) and it can explain the result but the deviation is small from the two measurements. In CM, it is a bit different and the output load resistance dominates the open-loop resistance. The output ripple can also play a role here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just a few short comments.

This data is just load regulation error.

Your voltage error vs current is mainly due to resistance ratio of series R to load R.  The series R includes inductor DCR, switch Ron   and/or Diode Rs.

When you use such a large L in your test, realize the step load from 100% to 50% causes a great step load voltage error V=LdI/dt and one in the 1 ~ 100uH range.  But a change from 2.2 to 1mH is not so significant.  This also means the start time is long. the XL(f)/R= Tau time for start time.

Also a large C reduces ripple but a large step Response time Tau=RC just delays the time for a voltage error with such a large C.

So now you know reactance has little effect on steady-state load regulation error.  It's the series R of those reactors.